# How to extract dict values and set as int variable?

Tags: python, dictionary

What I want to do is to extract the value of a dictionary to do calculations with it. My dictionary only has one value. But I'm not able to do calculations (+-*/) with dictionary values and I don't find a way to assign the value to an `int` variable.

```
a = {'number': 5}
b = a.values()
c = b*3
print(c)
```

The code produces the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'dict_values' and 'int'
```

Comment: Why don't you try `a['number']`?

Comment: `.values()` represents _all_ the values in a dictionary, such as 4 and 8 in `{'number': 4, 'number2': 8}` - since that's not an integer you can multiply, you're getting an error. As @TalhaTayyab comments, you can use the key directly to refer to a single value, so `a['number'] * 3` will work.

Comment: If you only have one value in your dictionary, I have to ask: why are you using a dictionary?

Comment: It's an API response. I just changed the first line directly to the response of the API.

Comment: If you know there's only one value, you can unpack the `dict_values` object with `b, = a.values()`.

Comment: If it's an API response, it seems like the key should be well defined and you can index the object properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.values()` returns *all* the values of the dictionary as a `dict_values`.

Of course, in your case that's only one value, but it's still in that form.

One thing that would work in this case:

```
a = {'number': 5}
b = a.values()
c = list(b)[0]*3
print(c)
```

The `dict_values` itself is a so-called view of the values of the dictionary, for reasons that are a bit too complicated to go into here - but as a result they cannot be indexed directly, so `c = b[0]*3` wouldn't work either.

Instead, the `dict_values` is converted into a `list` by passing it to the `list()` function, which accepts any iterable (like the `dict_values`) and creates a list from it. And the `list` *can* be indexed, so `list(b)[0]*3` takes the list of values, select the first (`[0]`) element, and multiplies that by `3`.

But what makes more sense:

```
a = {'number': 5}
b = a['number']
c = b*3
```

This just uses the dictionary as intended and selects the `'number'` value by indexing the dictionary with the key `a['number']`.

Or:

```
a = {'number': 5}
b = list(a.values())
c = [x*3 for x in b]
```

Since the dictionary *could* have more than one value, you could also take the list of values and multiply each element by 3 individually. But the result would have to be another collection, like this `list`.

Comment: I suggest adding a small explanation to each point so that OP can understand what's actually happening in the three different variations.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a cast. There's far more going on in `list(a.values())` than "treat this non-list as a list".

Comment: You're right - it's not a cast, the function constructs a new list from the iterable, changed.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you do not want to use list or list comprehension you can simply use:

```
a = {'number': 5}
for x in a.values():
   b=int(x)
c = b*3
```

Or as I commented:

```
a = {'number': 5}
b = a['number']
c = b*3
```

Comment: The issue with the first suggestion is that it will go through all the values in the dictionary and end up with `b` being the value of the *last*. Also, the `int` might fail for any keys that have a non-integer value, since a `dict` does not require all values to share their type. (and it's superfluous for the `'number'` value)

Comment: Dear @Grismar OP says that they only have 1 value in the list, and they have to do calculations with it; most probably it can be int or float.